# How do i save a numpy tensor to a file

Tags: numpy, tensor

I am trying to convert images to numpy tensor that is 4 dimensional and I want to save this into a file, preferrably a csv file. I already have the image array in the dimension I want them but now the problem is saving to a file. Please how do I go about doing this.

Comment: `csv` is a 2d format - neat rows on consistent columns.

Comment: yes, csv is 2d format, but an n dimensional tensor can be "flattened" to a 2d format.

Comment: it can be flattened in this way by adding columns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numpy has a lot of options for IO of array data:

- If binary format is Ok, you can use [np.save](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) to save the 4D tensor in a binary (".npy") format. The file can be read again with np.load. This is a very convenient way to save numpy data, and it works for numeric arrays of any number of dimensions.
- [np.savetxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) can write a 1D or 2D array in CSV-like text format. You could use np.reshape to flatten your tensor down to 1D or 2D and then use np.savetxt. The downside is the file doesn't keep track of the full 4D shape, so you'll need to track that separately in some way.
- If storing in text representation is important, a better option may be to convert the tensor to string with [np.array2string](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html#numpy.array2string), then write the string to file. This works even for arrays with more than 2 dimensions.
- The [.tofile method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html#numpy.ndarray.tofile) simply dumps the element data as a raw binary file. No shape or another other metadata is preserved, but the binary file is easy to read into other programs.